# Relationship of Fourier series and Hilbert spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series

I just read in a textbook that a Hilbert space can be defined or represented by an appropriate Fourier series. How might that be? Is it because a Fourier series is an infinite series that adequately "covers" a Hilbert space?

Apart from this I (a mathematical novice) have a hard time seeing the connection between a Hilbert space, a vector construct, and a Fourier series (of trigonometric functions).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The space of periodic $L^2$ functions (say with period $2\pi$) forms a Hilbert space.  (Here $L^2$ means that $\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)^2 dx$ exists.)

The inner product of two functions is given by $\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)g(x) dx$.
(Here and above I am thinking of real-valued functions; for complex valued functions the formulas are similar.)

Now we consider two facts, one about $L^2$-functions, and one about Hilbert space

- Every $L^2$-function can be expanded as a Fourier series.
- Every Hilbert space admits an orthonormal basis, and each vector in the Hilbert space can be expanded as a series in terms of this orthonormal basis.

It turns out that the first of these facts is a special case of the second:
we can interpret the trigonometric functions as an orthonormal basis of the
space of $L^2$-functions, and then the Fourier expansion of an arbitrary $L^2$-function *is* the same thing as its Hilbert space-theoretic expansion in terms of the orthonormal basis.

---

Summary/big picture: To see how a "vector construct" like Hilbert space relates to Fourier series, you don't consider a single function in isolation, but instead consider the entire vector space of $L^2$-functions, which is in fact a Hilbert space.

Comment: Nice answer. I'd only like to underline what I think is the key in the correspondence: in a Hilbert space, you have a notion of ``projection''. If you know the Gram-Schmidt procedure, you actually know the following: given an orthonormal basis $\{\phi_n\}_{n \in I}$ for a Hilbert space, one can write a function as $f = \sum_{n\in I} \langle f, \phi_n\rangle \phi_n.$ Now take $\phi_n = \cos(nx)$ and $\phi_m = \cos(mx)$ and the inner product Matt wrote down -- the sum becomes a Fourier series, and the $\langle f, \phi_n \rangle$ are Fourier coefficients!

Comment: Why do you need periodicity? As you wrote, *Every* $L^2$-function can be expanded as a Fourier series; not only periodic ones.

Answer (score 7):

To define the Fourier series of a function you need two things:

(i) the domain of the function needs to be a compact Abelian topological group $G$

(ii) an inner product on your space of functions

If you have this, then you can say the Fourier series of an $f: G \to \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ is the representation of $f$ in terms of the characters of $G$. The characters of a compact Abelian topological group are all continuous homomorphisms $G \to S^1$. This is why you need the domain to be a compact Abelian topological group.

Then you use that the characters of $G$ actually form a basis for the functions on $G$. But for this you need a way to define orthogonality and this is where the inner product comes in.

As it happens, if you take your function space to be $L^2 (G)$ with the usual inner product (as given in Matt E's answer) then this gives you a Hilbert space.

Comment: I hope this is not confusing. Matt's answer appeared while I was typing, so I'm posting it anyway.

Comment: Basically, your two necessary conditions for a Fourier series are also two necessary conditions for a Hilbert space, right?

Comment: @TomAu The inner product is but the group $G$ is not. You do have a group structure in a Hilbert space but note that the addition in this case is addition of functions, $f + g \in L^2 (G)$, not elements of the group $G$.

Comment: Technically you don't even need an inner product. See Rudin's Fourier analyis on groups. All you need is a locally compact topological group, and you can define the Fourier transform on $L^1(G)$. You can extend this construction to $L^2(G)$ (which does have an inner product) using the Plancherel theorem. So all that is needed is a group and a topology on that group.