# Examples of Abelian Topological Groups

Tags: general-topology, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, topological-groups

After reading an answer to the relation between [Fourier Series and Hilbert Spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184390/relationship-of-fourier-series-and-hilbert-spaces) I am curious about interesting examples of Abelian Topological Groups. Specifically, the answer explains that if $f$ has a fourier expansion the domain of $f$ must be an Abelian Topological Group.

A quick example that occurred to me was the metric space $(\mathbb{R}^n,+)$ equipped with the Euclidean distance metric. A topology can be defined in terms of balls $B(x,r)$ where $r > 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: The circle group, abelian groups with discrete topology, p-adic numbers and their unit groups, adeles and ideles...

Comment: If you are working with Fourier series and the Fourier transform, you may also want to restrict yourself a little more to locally compact topological groups.  Things get scary when you lose local compactness...

Comment: As Xander Henderson said. I think you need to impose local compactness to have a way of integrating (a Haar measure) since that is necessary for the definition of the Fourier transform.